# Code thesis' title page

Tags: titles, thesis, frontespizio

I want to make my thesis' title page like the one in the image below but I'm not able to reproduce it. Can somebody help me?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption} 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{graphicx}
\hyphenation{a-gen-tiz-za-zio-ne}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{-4.5cm} \mdseries{
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo.png}
% \psfig{file=./pictures/logopm.jpg,width=3.5cm}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
\Large
\textsc{Universit\`a di Firenze}\\
Scuola di Ingegneria\\
\vspace*{0.5cm}
\normalsize
Corso di Laurea Triennale in \textsc{Ingegneria Elettronica e delle Telecomunicazioni}\\
Dipartimento di \textsc{ Ingegneria dell'Informazione}\\
\vspace*{2cm} \LARGE



\textmd{TITOLO DELLA TESI}\\



\vspace*{1.5truecm} \small
Tesi di \\
\large
\vspace*{0.3cm}
Nome Candidato \\
\end{center}
\vspace*{2.0cm} \large
\begin{flushleft}
\small
Relatori:\\
\normalsize
\vspace*{0.5cm}
Ing. Nome Cognome \\
\vspace*{0.08cm}
Prof. Nome Cognome \\

\end{flushleft}
\vspace*{1.0cm}
\begin{flushleft}
\small
Candidato:\\
\normalsize
\vspace*{0.5cm}
Nome Cognome \\

\end{flushleft}
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{center}
\small

Sessione di Laurea 16 Luglio 2018\\
Anno Accademico 2017/2018
\end{center} \clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PeterWilson I've edited the question adding a MWE.

Answer (score 2):

In the follwing MWE I have added the horizontal lines as well as the dotted lines. Some vertical spaces might need further improvement, but this might give you some ideas.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{-4.5cm} 
\mdseries{

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}

{\Large
\textsc{Universit\`a di Firenze}\\
Scuola di Ingegneria}\\
\rule{7cm}{1pt}

\vspace*{0.5cm}

Corso di Laurea Triennale in \textsc{Ingegneria Elettronica e delle Telecomunicazioni}\\
Dipartimento di \textsc{ Ingegneria dell'Informazione}\\
\vspace*{2cm} 

{\LARGE
\textmd{TITOLO DELLA TESI}
}

\vspace*{1.5truecm} 

{\small
Tesi di
}

{\large
\vspace*{0.3cm}
Nome Candidato
}
\end{center}

\vspace*{2.0cm}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
\small
Relatori:\\[0.5cm]
\normalsize
\quad Ing. Nome Cognome & ..............................\\[0.1cm]
\quad Prof. Nome Cognome & ..............................\\[1cm]
\small
Candidato:\\[0.5cm]
\normalsize
\quad Nome Cognome & ..............................\\
\end{tabular}

\vfill

\begin{center}
\rule{3cm}{1pt}

\small
Sessione di Laurea 16 Luglio 2018\\
Anno Accademico 2017/2018
\end{center} 

\clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. The only problem that it doesn't solve is the "centering" of the contents of the title page. I've choosen to separate it in another file and I've used the package geometry in this way `\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm,top=6cm]{geometry}` and I've regulated manually the distances.